# Can't get data from url by using php ajax in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, get

I'm working on a plugin for wordpress, and want allow the administrator to save menu of the day in database. He would write the datas into a form (but not a real form like in html tag). I try to use Ajax from jQuery, but have a problem with $_GET[] in my php file, it's always tell me that the value is "null", and when I see in my parameter, it isn't null.

**JS FILE**

Here, no problem, but I ses that the link is encoded with "%" instead of "=", and think that could be the problem. But need our help to solve it.

```
function saveMenu(){

  e = event.target.id;
  objetXHR   = creationXHR();
  parametres ="";
  for (var i = 0; i < inputId.length; i++) {
    columnName = inputId[i];
    columnValue = elementValueArray[i];

    if( i < inputId.length-1){
      parametres = parametres + columnName + "=" + columnValue + "&";
    }else if(i  < inputId.length){
      parametres = parametres + columnName + "=" + columnValue;
    }
  };



        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET", //Use GET method
        url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data:{'action': 'insert_data', 'data' : json_parametres},
        success:function(response){
          alert(response)},
         error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
          {console.log(textStatus + " " + jqXHR + " " +errorThrown)}
     });
```

**PHP FILE**

I want to save the data in the database. What's happened is that the server save one line but all field are empty...

```
add_action('wp_ajax_insert_data', 'DBP_insert_my_data');

    function DBP_insert_my_data(){

        try{
            global $wpdb;
            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'daily_menu';
            //$inputMenuDate        =   $_REQUEST['inputMenuDate'];
            $inputEntreRow1     = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputEntreRow1']);
            $inputEntreRow2     = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputEntreRow2']);
            $inputEntreRow3     = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputEntreRow3']);
            $inputPlatRow1      = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputPlatRow1']);
            $inputPlatRow2      = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputPlatRow2']);
            $inputPlatRow3      = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputPlatRow3']);
            $inputPlatRow4      = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputPlatRow4']);
            $inputPlatRow5      = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputPlatRow5']);
            $inputDessertRow1   = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputDessertRow1']);
            $inputDessertRow2   = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputDessertRow2']);
            $inputDessertRow3   = addslashes($_REQUEST['inputDessertRow3']);
            $inputPrice             = $_REQUEST['inputPrice'];

                $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
                    'MenuDate'   => $inputMenuDate,
                    'EntreRow1'  => $inputEntreRow1,
                    'EntreRow2'  => $inputEntreRow2,
                    'EntreRow3'  => $inputEntreRow3,
                    'PlatRow1'   => $inputPlatRow1,
                    'PlatRow2'   => $inputPlatRow2,
                    'PlatRow3'   => $inputPlatRow3,
                    'PlatRow4'   => $inputPlatRow4,
                    'PlatRow5'   => $inputPlatRow5,
                    'DessertRow1'=> $inputDessertRow1,
                    'DessertRow2'=> $inputDessertRow2,
                    'DessertRow3'=> $inputDessertRow3,
                    'MenuPrice'  => $inputPrice
                ));


                wp_send_json($inputMenuDate);
            }

            catch(PDOException $e){
                $response = ["Error" => $e->getMessage];
            wp_send_json($response);
            }

            wp_die();

    }
```

Hope someone can help me...Thank You!